# Pass multiple user input to ssh remote command

Tags: ssh, interactive, git-pull, remotecommand

I'm trying to make a script that creates a ssh connection and executes a remote command which needs multiple user interactions. The remote script expects two passwords sequentially. One of another ssh connection and one for a git pull (ssh-)command.

**Local script (run manually):**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Password 1: "
read -s password_1
echo

echo -n "Password 2: "
read -s password_2
echo

result=$(ssh -t user@remote_host "/path/to/remote_script.bs" 2>&1 <<EOF
echo "$password_1"
echo "$password_2"
EOF
)

echo "$result"
```

**Remote script (remote_script.bs):**

```
# expects first password
ssh -M -S ".ssh_socket" -fNT "fixed_user@git_server" -L 1234:192.168.24.99:22
# expects seconds password; git is configured to pull via localhost portforwarding of ssh connection above
git --git-dir "path_to_git/.git" pull
```

The remote interactions ignore the echoed passwords and rush into a failed authentication.

Due to diverse environments I cant'use expect or sshpass.

Comment: You are (twice) passing the actual string `echo` plus the quotemarks plus the entered password, e.g. `echo "mysecret"` not just `mysecret`. These are presumably not the correct password values. Use _just_ `$password_1` and `$password_2` as the lines of the heredoc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Dave. Unfortunately just using the variables (without quuotemarks and without echo) has the same behaviour and results in a failed authentication.